# LVDS for TFT touch display

Tags: display, lvds, ide

I have a hardware with the LVDS interface to control the display.
My question: Which programming language and IDE would be most suitable for programming LVDS? Or is it possible with any language like FPGA, C++ or even Python?
I am unsure because of the higher speed.

Please excuse my delayed reaction.
My goal is to develop a GUI for the TFT display.
I have not yet defined the display I will use, if I get a display without the necessary drivers, is it better to program the drivers or is it faster without the drivers.

Many thanks in advance

Comment: Welcome. Could you please give more details about your hardware? Link to the datasheets or at least part numbers will do.

Comment: The CPU used is the following: https://www.karo-electronics.de/fileadmin/download/Datasheets/TX6S-Datasheet.pdf                                                                     Unfortunately, I am not allowed to release any schematics of the hardware.

Comment: A very warm welcome to the site. Please can you edit your question and add the manufacturer and their part number of the LCD, preferably with a link to the datasheet. Can't really go any further without info. Thanks.

Comment: LVDS is an interface. You don't "program" LVDS, same as you don't program a USB port. You probably mean either "program a driver for the LVDS interface", or "prgram an application that displays stuff on the screen", which are both very very different problematics. "program a driver" can't be done in python, but can be skipped entirely, if you just slap Linux on that board (which is probably the best idea). And "program an application" then becomes simple, but kind of off-topic on this site. Also note: neither the driver nor the app need to work at the speed the LVDS interface spits out bits.

Comment: @dim, LVDS is a differential signalling standard, not an interface, and I'm pretty certain it's not a software driver they need here. Let's get the LCD datasheet before throwing out anything else.

Comment: @TonyM He gave the datasheet, it's a board that contains a i.MX6 SoC, which includes the LVDS Interface. i.MX6 datasheet can be found easily. Now, if the software driver isn't what they need, what is it they need? The application that display stuff? I considered this. I can't think of anything else that requires a programming language and an IDE.

Answer (score 3):

The answer is none because it cannot be programmed.

Either your hardware has an LVDS interface or it doesn't.

You can't make any MCU to output video if it does not have a display controller, and display controllers may have various different output buses, and if it does not have FPD ("LVDS") video output it might have the output in another format that might be possible to convert to FPD externally.

Some FPGAs can have pins that are able to work with LVDS electrical interface.

These FPGA pins may have hardware support for serializing the video data into FPD-Link format before it is sent out as LVDS. For low resolution formats with slow data rates, it may be possible to make the serialization in logic instead of hardware serializer.

You still need to generate the video stream somehow before converting in into FPD-Link stream and sent over LVDS. Discrete chips can do that as well, if you aleady have a parallel video interface.

FPGA is not a language, it is a hardware that runs digital logic you define, in some language.

If you simply talk about using the framebuffer to manipulate what is shown on screen, use any language you want. Same way if you have a PC, you can write a game where user can control some things on screen in any language that allows such programs to be made.